# type '[[String : AnyObject]]' has no subscript members

Tags: json, swift, parsing

```
[let appUrl = URL(string: "some link")!

let data = try Data(contentsOf: appUrl)

let json2 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

let post = json2["posts"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]

// here I want to connect to image but its still tell me the problem  
//type '[[String : AnyObject]]' has no subscript members              
let image = post["image"] as [[String:AnyObject]]
print(image)
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual structure of your JSON? You've declared `post` as an array of dictionary but then you try to treat `post` as a dictionary on the next line.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: Can you post some sample structure of your JSON?

Comment: func fetchArticles() {
        
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://mahmudhajialiyev.com/api/get_posts/")!)
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in
            
            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return

Comment: }
            self.articles = [Baza]()
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
                if let articlesFromJson = json["posts"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
                    for articleFromJson in articlesFromJson{
                        let article = Baza()
                    if let title = articleFromJson["title"] as? String, let url = articleFromJson["url"] as? String, let imageUrl = articleFromJson["thumbnail"] as? String {

Comment: article.headline = title
                            article.url = url
                            article.imageUrl = imageUrl
                        }
                       self.articles?.append(article)
                    }
                    //type '[[String : AnyObject]]' has no subscript members
            }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

Comment: Please add this to th Q, not in comments. Nobody can read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you defined

```
// Array of [[String:AnyObject]]
let post = json2["posts"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

And what you gonna try to use is

```
let image = post["image"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //Wrong
```

Is that possible to access array of post with "image" string index? You have to pass index to `post` array

```
 // index may be changed or you can iterate post array.
let image = post?[2]["image"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] //Right
```

Hope you will get idea what you had done and what you have to do.

Comment: Thank you! its help me but one question more I have more index not only [2] what I can write?                                                                                       let image = post?[2]["image"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]  //What I have to change [2] to show all my array ? thanks !

Comment: @MahmudHacialiyev If you provide you json structure then i will give some suggestions to you.